# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Oracle VirtualBox in sub-directory

Tags: 18.04

Is it possible to install the new bootable operating system i.e. Ubuntu 18.4 LTS in a folder that is located inside a partition ? Do I need to empty and format the whole partition of the drive or it can be installed in a allocated sub-folder ?

Comment: VirtualBox offers virtual storage devices. You don't need to do anything special to the host to make them work. If you would like the virtual devices to be stored on a separate disk or even a USB drive, simply choose the save location at the time of defining the virtual storage device.

Comment: Is it possible to chose a sub-folder location for the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in VirtualBox ? Usually we have partitions like C, D, E etc. Is it possible to do the installation in the E:/temp/OracleVM ?

Comment: The VM storage devices can be put anywhere. If you're using Windows as a host machine, [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-in-virtualbox/) will walk you through the whole process of getting Ubuntu (or any other OS) set up in VirtualBox 